# Is there a power series expansion of the Signum function?

Tags: power-series

I would like to define a linear operator as the sign of a another operator. But to use it I would need to expand it out as a power series.

Roughly, I'm wondering if something like this

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathrm{Sgn}\left(\hat{O}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}C_{n}\hat{O}^{n}
\end{eqnarray}

exists?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to make up an operator like $\operatorname{Sgn}(\frac d{dx})$ where, perhaps, $\operatorname{Sgn}(\frac d{dx})e^{ax}=\operatorname{Sgn}(a)e^{ax}$ or something?

Comment: @columbus8myhw Yes, something quite similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A power series that converges for a certain $x_0$ converges *absolutely* for all $x$ with $|x|<|x_0|$ and then the limit function is necessarily continuous. Since the sign function is not continuous, no such series exists.

Comment: More precisely, continuity follows from the fact there is *total* convergence (or convergence of the norms) in any closed interval $[-\delta,\delta]$ for positive $\delta$ less than the radius of convergence.

Comment: Well that makes life trickier. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the other post by Hagen von Eitzen, this is not possible due to the discontinuity of the Sign function at $x = 0$. Having said that, you are obviously free to circumvent this difficulty by representing the Sign function as the limit of a continuous sigmoidal function. For example, $f(x) = tanh(x/ \epsilon)$ will do fine. This function can be expanded in a power series without difficulty, and in the limit of $\epsilon$ to zero the function is equal to the Sign function.

Comment: This is potentially quite helpful. Thank you.

Comment: By the way, you mean ArcTan, correct?

Comment: Never mind, both work.

Comment: There are several choices for the sigmoidal function. I would probably choose $tanh(x/ \epsilon)$, but $arctan(x/ \epsilon)$ should also work fine. Then there is $x/ \sqrt (x^2 + \epsilon ^2)$. And the error-function. Obviously they all have different series expansions. It is up to you to make a choice. Good luck with your project !